# Aggregate values in a javascript grouped object based on conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am using IE 11.

I have an object array that is grouped using the lodash library.  I want to be able to query the object and based on certain conditions come up with sums/counts.  So for example, I have this object array.

[image: Object Array]

I would like to have the result seen below but in an object like the image above
[image]

As you can see, each company in the group should have certain values based on the following criteria

How many times does 'company x' have a Total Count >3?
How many times does 'company x' have expectingFunding eq ‘Yes’>
How many times does 'company x' have fundedOnIKNS eq ‘No’?

I've tried quite a bit in the last couple of days but not success.  I first declared 2 arrays so I can capture the unique values of company name and program.  I also created  an object to update when conditions were met.  The only successful thing I was able to get was to keep it in an grouped object.  All the values in the new object were wrong.

Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
const companiesSummary = {};
for (const company of Object.keys(myData)) {
  companiesSummary[company] = {
    totalCount: 0,
    expectedFunding: 0,
    IKNSFunding: 0,
  };

  for (const { TotalCount, expectedFunding, fundedOnIKNS } of myData[company]) {
      companiesSummary[company].totalCount += TotalCount;
      companiesSummary[company].expectedFunding += expectedFunding === "Yes";
      companiesSummary[company].fundedOnIKNS += fundedOnIKNS === "Yes";
  }
}
```

I get the error,

> TypeError: myData[company] is not iterable

Here's a link to the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/PoYRLNo?editors=0010)

I would still like the result to be in an object array, so I can create an html table later.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're taking `myData`, an array, accessing `myData[company]`, an object (company is 0, 1, ...), and you can't iterate through an object with `for...of`. `myData` is definitely not the same object in your screenshot.

Your code excerpt might work if your `myData` object were the object in your screenshot.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I did not pass ```myData``` through lodash ```_.groupBy```.  Thanks for the 2nd eye.  It works now.